# cache.addAll not getting all resources

Tags: reactjs, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

when I use cache.addAll in my react component, I expect it to fetch the resources which I would then expect to trigger the fetch event in my serviceworker, which in turn I would expect to cache the resource i.e all resources for that URL would then be cached

I have a button in my React component that does a cache.addAll on a number of URLS. These URLs if opened manually will trigger js that then does an Axios call to get data. If I run this manually, the axios requests are intercepted by the serviceworker fetch event handler and the responses are put into the cache. But if I use cache.addAll it just gets my index page so when I then try to access it offline the further calls to get data then fail.
I could analyze the urls and cache every call that they do so the full page is available offline but I was hoping I could just use cache.addAll.
Is there another way without working out all the sub urls for each page?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you have an html page that loads a number of javascript resources that make requests to a number of API endpoints. From the html page you are calling `addAll` to cache the js resources but you also want to cache the API responses?

Comment: not exactly but almost. My app is a React SPA, so basically consists of one index.html and a javascript file. These are both cached at start up. If I navigate from /products to, say, /products/MYPROD, in the normal course of things, this would trigger api calls and because I have setup dynamic caching in the service worker, these api calls would be cached immediately. But if I use cache.add from /products to add /products/MYPROD, it doesn't actually trigger those api calls (which in turn my sw would have cached). It fetches the response, which of course is just my index.html but nothing else.

Comment: @user2047485 is you app support SSR? If not, Service Worker will request to 404 file.

Comment: no SSR. It does not give 404. When online I use cache.addAll with a route that is supported in my SPA. This caches index.html. If I go offline and access this route, I get the index.html but then the api calls made in the React lifecycle fail because they have not been cached.
If I had just navigated to that route while online though, the api calls would have been cached via the fetch intercept in the service worker

Comment: So it sounds like you are doing `addAll` for the path shown in the URL bar which will fetch another version of the `index.html` page. What you want to do is `addAll` the API URLs so that when the specific product is rendered the HTML, JS, and data are all cached.

Comment: yes thanks. I am doing this now but of course it means knowing all the api urls that are called by the pages I want to cache. I was hoping that caching the page url would trigger a fetch on that page which would then trigger the api calls which would then be cached by the service-worker fetch event handler. But it seems that the fetch of the page does not trigger the associated javascript - probably makes sense, just makes it harder